# No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type xx

Tags: typescript

These are the types I am using:

```
export interface IHelpDeskTextData {
  supportPaneltext: ContactHelpdeskContex[];
  selected?: number | null;
  brandOptions?: string[];
  textPanel?: ITextPanel[];
}

export class ContactHelpdeskContex {
  public brand: string;
  public paragraphList: IParagraph[];
}
interface IParagraph {
  rowList: string[];
}

export interface ITextPanel {
  textContent: IParagraph[];
  selected: boolean;
  brand: string;
}
```

I have a variables with data of type:

```
public supportPaneltext: ContactHelpdeskContex[];
public textPanel: ITextPanel[] = [];
```

I try to do create a new variable via the map function of above variable:

```
public getLabel() {
    if (!this.supportPaneltext) {
      return;
    }

    this.textPanel = Object.values(this.supportPaneltext).map((item,i) => {
      return {
        brand: item[i].brand,
        selected: false,
        textContent: item[i].paragraphList
      }}
      )}
```

However, I get this error when I try to use the index [i]:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'ContactHelpdeskContex'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'ContactHelpdeskContex'.
```

How come, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appear because you try index `ContactHelpdeskContex` with `i` like follow: `item[i].brand`. It's caused by fact that value passed to `.map()` method (`item` here) is specific element of array not array itself, you can read how map work  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Simple remove `[i]`

```
public getLabel() {
    if (!this.supportPaneltext) {
        return;
    }

    this.textPanel = Object.values(this.supportPaneltext).map(item => ({
        brand: item.brand,
        selected: false,
        textContent: item.paragraphList
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you don't need to use `Object.values` to iterate through an array and secondly you already have an array element in `item` so you don't need to use the index variable `i`:

```js
this.textPanel = this.supportPaneltext.map((item) => {
      return {
        brand: item.brand,
        selected: false,
        textContent: item.paragraphList
      }
      }
      )
```